# Flutter- Firebase Storage upload video

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I would like to upload video in `Firebase Storage`.
I tried like so.

```
 Future uploadToStorage() async {
    try {
      final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      final int millSeconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      final String month = now.month.toString();
      final String date = now.day.toString();
      final String storageId = (millSeconds.toString() + uid);
      final String today = ('$month-$date'); 

      final file = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

      StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("video").child(today).child(storageId);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

      Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;

        final String url = downloadUrl.toString();

     print(url);

    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      }

    }
```

But the problem is that I uploaded 3 different videos. one is from real device and the others are from Ios simulator and only one video from simulator was recognized as video like this image.

[image: image here]

> File: /Users/Daibaku/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C99406E4-12F3-480A-82A6-F6144ADD21AB/data/Containers/Data/Application/23E82E18-9293-4EEB-AEEA-6A873F2F7CD7/tmp/image_picker_0B59CC5B-BB53-4019-BA8E-5F219374D8C8-7394-000006A2FA530CD0.MOV'
>
> File:
>   '/Users/Daibaku/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C99406E4-12F3-480A-82A6-F6144ADD21AB/data/Containers/Data/Application/23E82E18-9293-4EEB-AEEA-6A873F2F7CD7/tmp/image_picker_F9355517-8C5C-4804-9312-69E1696CAF87-7394-000006A80D46F0B7.MOV'

Those are file path from similator and bottom one was recognized as video.
Does anyone know what is happening and how to fix it?
Thank you!

**Edit**
 sorry actually last one on the image was uploaded manually(I put into storage from my finder). So, both simulator and real device can't upload video.

Comment: You can consider storing videos with a dedicated media api instead of firebase storage, I wrote about it here: https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-video-sharing-app-with-flutter-and-firebase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked it out. The point is you have to specify the metadata content type manually like so.

```
Future uploadToStorage() async {
try {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int millSeconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  final String month = now.month.toString();
  final String date = now.day.toString();
  final String storageId = (millSeconds.toString() + uid);
  final String today = ('$month-$date'); 

 final file =  await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("video").child(today).child(storageId);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4')); <- this content type does the trick

  Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;

    final String url = downloadUrl.toString();

 print(url);

} catch (error) {
  print(error);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you please mark that as the solution to this issue? So everybody knows the right answer :) thx

Comment: Sorry about that I did, thanks for your suggestion:)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in flutter web?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I guess firebase storage is not ready for flutter web yet.

Comment: do we still need to pass metadata manually? I was trying this code but it shows red line below file,StorageMetadata

Comment: SettableMetadata