# How to upload videos to firebase storage and get their uploading progress?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, video-upload

I have these recorded videos which exist in the app directory that I want the app to upload them to firebase storage and get the progress percentage, I know how to upload from gallery but not from app directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get recorded videos from your application directory.

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Comment: then ? the same way as the gallery ?

Comment: Yes the only goal here to upload is to get paths of files and that we can with path_provider.

Comment: ok can u post the way to upload a video to firebase storage ?

Comment: Please share your code where you are uploading videos already with gallery.

Comment: cause I saw ways using image picker that must include some sources but not the app directory.

Comment: Here, I got it from this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822789/flutter-firebase-storage-upload-video)

Comment: or if u have a way to save the videos in gallery ?